# Using iter().map on a VecDeque of struct containing tuples

Tags: rust, deque

I have the following problem:

```
pub struct Events {
    pub ts: u64,
    pub temperature_multiplier: (f64,f64), // (temperature,multiplier)
}
```

I have a VecDeque of this struct

```
elements_vec: VecDeque<Events>
```

I would like to be able to go through all the elements of VecDeque and compute the the sum of (temperature * multiplier).

What I have tried:

```
elements_vec.iter().map(|(_, (t,m))| t * m ).sum()
```

It returns an error saying "expected Struct Events".

Answer (score 1):

`Events` is not a tuple but a struct. You need to go through [Destructuring Structs section in rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#destructuring-structs).

```rust
elements_vec.iter().map(|Events { temperature_multiplier: (t, m), .. }| t * m).sum::<f64>()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood your question:

```
let mut elements_vec: VecDeque<Events> = VecDeque::with_capacity(10);
elements_vec.push_back(Events { ts: 0x0002, temperature_multiplier: (20.0, 2.0) });
elements_vec.push_back(Events { ts: 0x0003, temperature_multiplier: (30.0, 3.0) });
elements_vec.push_front(Events { ts: 0x0001, temperature_multiplier: (10.0, 1.0) });

println!("{:?}", &elements_vec);

let s : f64 = elements_vec.iter().map(|evnt| evnt.temperature_multiplier.0 * evnt.temperature_multiplier.1 ).sum();

println!("s: {}", s); // s: 140
```

The answer is in the compiler's message: `map()` needs `struct Events`, which we give it as `map(|evnt| /* and use it here */)`. And it works!